# How to recover files from the command "git clean -df"

Tags: macos, github, recover

I am using the Mac OS x, and i was sooooooooo stupid to run the "git clean -df", it delete all my folders and files.

Those documents are very important for me, there is nothing in Trash, and i try to download some software to help me to recover files, but no working...

I am really worried, please help me !

Comment: Not all files but only these that were `untracked` by `git`. It's going to be hard to get them back unless you have a backup as according to `man git-clean`: `Remove untracked files from the working tree`. As these files were not tracked by `git`, you cannot get them back with `git`. You *should not* run commands you don't understand.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk No, I run this command in my whole environment, it delete all my folders(of course, i never want to upload this onto github), so my computer now just have the same files like github!!!

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, i know, i am so stupid T.T.  I really hate my action just now!!

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by `I run this command in my whole environment`.

Comment: I don't use `MacOS` but I heard there is something called `Time Machine` or similar, you may look into it to restore removed files. `Git` will not help you here.

Comment: Time Machine, need i have a backup, but i have nothing

Comment: You might want to try asking this on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ . It's more a question about Mac OS X than about programming.